# How to prove a result related to prime number theorem in research paper of Rivoal and Zudilin

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Question is ->I am studying research paper: A note on odd zeta values and I am unable to think how to deduce a result which the authors don't prove. This result has to be proved assuming the prime number theorem and it's on Page 12 of the paper :

> Prove that $\lim_ {n\to\infty}  \frac{\log(\Phi_n) } {n} =\int_0^{1}
>  \rho_0 (t) d(\psi(t) + 1/t) $, where $\psi(t) $ = $\frac {\Gamma'(t) }
> {\Gamma(t) }  $.

where $\Phi(n)$ and $\rho(n)$ are described in this image:
[image: definitions of Phi and rho]

Can someone please tell how to prove this result ?

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: This question already had an accepted answer. Why have you bumped it with an edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we start by partitioning the range of summation into intervals on which $\rho_0(\frac np)$ is constant, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\log \Phi_n &= \sum_{2\sqrt n<p\le n} \rho_0\big( \tfrac np \big) \log p \\
&= \sum_{k=6}^{3\sqrt n-1} \sum_{\frac{6n}{k+1} < p \le \frac{6n}k} \rho_0\big( \tfrac np \big) \log p \\
&= \sum_{k=6}^{3\sqrt n-1} \rho_0\big( \tfrac k6 \big) \sum_{\frac{6n}{k+1} p \le \frac{6n}k}  \log p = \sum_{k=6}^{3\sqrt n-1} \rho_0\big( \tfrac k6 \big) \big( \theta\big( \tfrac{6n}k \big) - \theta \big( \tfrac{6n}{k+1} \big) \big),
\end{align*}
where $\theta(x) = \sum_{p\le x} \log p \sim x$ by the prime number theorem. Thus
\begin{align*}
\log \Phi_n &\sim \sum_{k=6}^{3\sqrt n-1} \rho_0\big( \tfrac k6 \big) \big( \tfrac{6n}k - \tfrac{6n}{k+1} \big) \sim 6n \sum_{k=6}^\infty \frac{\rho_0(k/6)}{k(k+1)}.
\end{align*}
A similar partitioning calculation on the integral will hopefully lead to the same result.

Comment: in the fifth line of your answer how did you change $\sum_{2√n<p$\leq$n$ = $\sum_{k=6}^{3√n-1}$ $\sum_{6n/(k+1) p$\leq$6n/k) . Can you please elaborate why it is right?

Comment: There was a typo (now fixed). We're just splitting up the interval of summation from the first line into $3\sqrt n-1$ consecutive intervals of summation.

Comment: how did you deduced that p lies between 6n/k+1 and 6n/k ? I am not able to think about it. Can you please tell.

Comment: On the first line, every prime between $2\sqrt n$ and $n$ appears exactly once, and smaller or larger primes don't appear at all. On the second line, do any primes smaller than $2\sqrt n$ or larger than $n$ appear? Given a prime $p$ between $2\sqrt n$ and $n$, for how many values of $k$ will $p$ appear in the inner sum?

Comment: We're just splitting up the range of summation into intervals on which the function is simpler. A strong analogy would be the computation $$\int_0^N \lfloor x\rfloor^2\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \int_k^{k+1} \lfloor x\rfloor^2\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} k^2 \int_k^{k+1} 1\,dx.$$

Comment: thanks!! Now that question is clear. But I have one question still if you don't mind, in  3 rd = how in RHS of = you Put $\rho_0(n/p) $ out of summation by putting$\rho_0(k/6) $ . I can get only up to k+1/6 > n/p $\geq$ k/6 . I am sorry but I can't get it.

Comment: Check out the definition of $\rho_0$ ... on an interval of the form $[\frac k6,\frac{k+1}6)$, how many different values does $\rho_0$ take? (This, in fact, is the motivation for that specific splitting-up choice.)

Comment: @DxdxDxdx: Please restrict to one question per post. BTW if your professor has abandoned you, then you might as well switch to a different topic and work on it on your own. Or find another professor.

Comment: @DxdxDxdx: I take back "Please restrict to one question per post". Perhaps you can also discuss this topic with friends/classmates. You can also contact the authors of the paper, they are mathematicians just like those who respond here. They will be delighted to hear you write a thesis based on their work.

Comment: @DxdxDxdx: I don't have time for this right now. Also, it is not too much fun to help students understand a particular line from a paper that is not close to my research. I think your best shot is to contact the authors. As I said, they are mathematicians just like me, but they have the advantage that *they* wrote the paper, and you write a thesis about *their* work. So don't be shy, just drop them an email!

Comment: @YemonChoi Your comment is unkind. I request you to delete it. Can you please do that?

Comment: @Arnold are you referring to my comment asking why you have bumped the question to the top page through editing? I don't think that is an unkind comment; I think it is a reasonable question, given that you already accepted an answer to this question more than a year ago.

Comment: @YemonChoi No. I am not talking about that comment. The comment which I asked you to delete has been deleted by you or the moderators since I also flagged that comment. It's nothing personal.